# arranging the records in customised way

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

**Sort Procedure**
First sort by the delivered date & in case of multiple records  on same date sort by delivered time (Note: if a record has both ordered and Delivered Date ,it should be sorted by Delivered date only)

08-JUN: 03.00,
08-JUN: 04.00

Then look at the ordered date without delivered date which also exists for 08-JUN & sort by ordered date if multiple records on same date sort by ordered time

08-JUN:  02.00

Then go back to the next delivered date & in case of multiple records sort by  delivered time

09-JUN:  01.00,
09-JUN:  12.00

Then  look at the ordered date without delivered date which also exists for 09-JUN & sort by ordered date if multiple records on same date sort by ordered time

09-JUN:  14.00

```
                   **ordered date**   **orderTime**   **DeliveredDate**   **DeliveredTime**
                        24-NOV-2021      10.00            24-NOV-2021    12.00
                            -                -            24-NOV-2021    09.00
                        25-NOV-2021       9.00               -             -
                        25-NOV-2021      11.00            26-NOV-2021    12.00
                        25-NOV-2021      10.00               -             -
                        26-NOV-2021      02.00               -             -
                            -              -               10-DEC-2021     03.00
                            -                  -           10-DEC-2021    02.00
                        26-NOV-2021      04.00                -            -
                        27-NOV-2021      07.00
                        30-NOV-2021      08.00                -            -
                        28-NOV-2021      12.00
                        27-NOV-2021      14.00                 -           -
```

//Output should be like the following .->
**ordered date**   **orderTime**   **DeliveredDate**   **DeliveredTime**

```
                              -                -              24-NOV-2021    09.00
                            24-NOV-2021      10.00            24-NOV-2021    12.00
                            25-NOV-2021       9.00               -             -
                            25-NOV-2021      11.00            26-NOV-2021    12.00
                            26-NOV-2021      02.00
                            26-NOV-2021      04.00                -            -
                            27-NOV-2021      07.00                -            -
                            27-NOV-2021      14.00                 -           -
                            28-NOV-2021      12.00                 -           -
                            30-NOV-2021      08.00                -            -
                                 -              -             10-DEC-2021     03.00
                                 -              -             10-DEC-2021     02.00
```

---

```
//The code I tried.not giving exp OP. any other way ?.->
int compareVal;
if(o1.getDeliveredDate() != null && o2.getDeliveredDate()!=null){
    compareValue  = (o1.getDeliveredDate().compareTo(o2.getDeliveredDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0 && o1.getDeliveredTime() != null && o2.getDeliveredTime() != null) {
        return (o1.getDeliveredTime().compareTo(o2.getDeliveredTime()));
    }
    return comparevalue;
} else if(o1.getDeliveredDate() != null & && o2.getDeliveredDate()==null) {
    compareValue  = (o1.getDeliveredDate().compareTo(o2.getOrderedDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0 ) {
        return -1;
    }
    return comparevalue;
} else if(o1.getDeliveredDate() == null & && o2.getDeliveredDate()!=null) {
    compareValue  = (o2.getDeliveredDate().compareTo(o1.getOrderedDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    return comparevalue;
} else if(o1.getDeliveredDate() == null && o2.getDeliveredDate()==null &&
        o1.getOrderedDate() != null && o2.getOrderedDate()!=null) {
    compareValue  = (o1.getOrderedDate().compareTo(o2.getOrderedDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0 && o1.getOrderedTime() != null && o2.getOrderedTime() != null) {
        return (o1.getOrderedTime().compareTo(o2.getOrderedTime()));
    }
}
return compareVal;
```

Comment: What are the type of `[delivered|ordered]Date and Time`?

Comment: Date  -Java util  (delivered and ordered date).   String  for Ordered Time and Delivered Time

Comment: If one order is ordered 24 Nov and delivered 28 Nov and another order is ordered 26 Nov and delivered the same day, where should a third order ordered 25 Nov and without delivery date be fit into the sorted sequence?

Comment: 25 Nov without delivered date should come at top. nxt  26 nov record  and last  24 nov- 28 nov

Comment: Thanks. But in your expected output order date `26-NOV-2021      02.00` does not come before delivery date `26-NOV-2021    12.00`, so I still haven’t completely understood. Are you requirements well-defined and consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your output, the last two must be reversed. Here's the corrected comparison order. It assumes time will be present when date is there.

```
if (o1.getOrderedDate() != null && o2.getOrderedDate() != null) {
    compareValue = (o1.getOrderedDate().compareTo(o2.getOrderedDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0) {
       return o1.getOrderedTime().compareTo(o2.getOrderedTime());
    }
    return compareValue;
} else if (o1.getDeliveredDate() != null && o2.getDeliveredDate() != null) {
    compareValue = (o1.getDeliveredDate().compareTo(o2.getDeliveredDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0) {
        return o1.getDeliveredTime().compareTo(o2.getDeliveredTime());
    }
    return compareValue;
} else if (o1.getDeliveredDate() == null && o2.getOrderedDate() == null) {
    compareValue = (o1.getOrderedDate().compareTo(o2.getDeliveredDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0) {
        return o1.getOrderedTime().compareTo(o2.getDeliveredTime());
    }
    return compareValue;
} else {
    compareValue = (o1.getDeliveredDate().compareTo(o2.getOrderedDate()));
    if (compareValue == 0) {
        return o1.getDeliveredTime().compareTo(o2.getOrderedTime());
    }
    return compareValue;
}
```

Note: For comparing two time values, you shouldn't rely on String's natural ordering. For example: It considers `11` < `9`. If you always have `0` prefixed for hours 0 to 9, then you are good.

#### Another simpler way

In essence, you want to compare two Date/time from two objects (let me call it `MyDateTime` as the class name) i.e., given two `MyDateTime` instances, you want to pick the *date* and *time* of *order* - if not present, pick the *date* and *time* of *delivery* otherwise.

Once you have a *date* and *time* pair (either order/delivery) compare them with the other *date* and *time* pair of some other `MyDateTime` instance.

Let me define two helper functions for getting the Date and Integer objects to be used for comparison.

```
private static Date getDateForComparison(MyDateTime myDateTime) {
    if (myDateTime.getOrderedDate() != null) {
        return myDateTime.getOrderedDate();
    }
    return myDateTime.getDeliveredDate();
}
private static String getTimeForComparison(MyDateTime myDateTime) {
    if (myDateTime.getOrderedTime() != null) {
        return myDateTime.getOrderedTime();
    }
    return myDateTime.getDeliveredTime();
}
```

Then, we can write a simple comparator as:

```
Comparator<MyDateTime> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyDateTime::getDateForComparison)
            .thenComparing(MyDateTime::getTimeForComparison);
```

---

P.S: Java `Date` class is not recommended and must be treated as deprecated. Check on the Java 8+ alternate for it.